Put submodule .git folder into working directory
We have a directory tree like this:
.
├── README.md
├── .git
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── code-server-images
│   │       └── code-server
│   │           ├── modules
│   │           │   └── lib
│   │           │       └── vscode
│   │           │           └── ...
│   │           └── ...
│   └── ...
├── code-server-images
│   ├── code-server
│   │   ├── .git    "gitdir: ../../.git/modules/code-server-images/code-server"
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── vscode
│   │   │       ├── .git    "gitdir: ../../../../.git/modules/code-server-images/code-server/modules/lib/vscode"
│   │   │       └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── images
│   │   └── base.containerfile
│   └── ...
└── ...

When building the code-server images, we only copy the contents of code-server-images/code-server into the image. But at some point, the build script of code-server / vscode runs some git commands and git tries to resolve the gitdir entry and fails:
fatal: not a git repository: /app/lib/vscode/../../../../.git/modules/code-server-images/code-server/modules/lib/vscode

I would like to avoid copying the whole repository into the image, even if I exclude directories that are not needed.
Is it possible to move the .git directory of the submodules into their working directories?

code-server-images/code-server/.git is not a directory but a text file. When building the images I think you can just remove it as it points to nowhere. Or properly clone the submodule from its repository.
